# How do I create a pdf whose style is correct and is created with Haml with Wicked-pdf's pdf_from_string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml, wicked-pdf

I am trying to make a pdf with QRcode which is made with Haml file on my application.
My application is on ruby on rails and uses `ActiveStorage`, and QRcode is made with `rqrcode`.

First, I tried to make `controller's instance` and `view's instance`.
Then I created a pdf with `WickedPdf.new.pdf_from_string` and `Haml file` is loaded with `view` which is an instance I created before.

The pdf is created but the style in `Haml file` did not work.

Is it lacking any helper that is required to extend with the `view` or something else problem?

This is a `Haml` code. The pdf is supposed to be created alongside this code.

```
%div.content
  %div.block.block-rounded.block-bordered.block-fx-shadow.justify-content-center
    %div.block-header
      %h3.block-title= I18n.t('word.qrcode')
    %div.block-content
      = show_qr(@remote_interview_url_with_iid)
```

`show_qr` successfully returns QRCode svg.

This is the code which creates instances, pdf; and attaches to `active storage`.

```
def attach_pdf
    controller = ActionController::Base.new
    view = ActionView::Base.new(Rails.root.join('app', 'views'), {}, controller)
    view.extend(ApplicationHelper)
    pdf = WickedPdf.new.pdf_from_string(view.render(template: 'layouts/pdf.html.haml', encoding: 'UTF-8'))
    self.pdf.attach(io: StringIO.new(pdf), filename: "pdf_#{self.iid}.pdf", content_type: 'application/pdf')
  end
```

This is the code which is linked to the pdf page.

```
= link_to interview.pdf_url do
  %button.btn.btn-outline-primary.font-w600
    = I18n.t('word.show_qrcode')
```

`pdf_url` successfully returns an attached pdf's url.

I wanna know how to let the `view instance` loads `Haml` code correctly.